# How to use File /r without recursing input directories

Tags: nsis

I have a directory structure which looks like this:

```
parent-dir
  XXX
    file.txt
    YYY
      file2.txt
  CCC
    XXX
      file3.txt
```

I currently use `File /r XXX` to recursively get parent-dir\XXX but because /r also causes File to search the input directories recursively I also get all of parent-dir\CCC\XXX.

I realize I could `CreateDirectory XXX` and `SetOutputPath XXX` and use `File /r XXX\*` and then `SetOutputPath` back but I don't want to have to do that every time I use `File /r`

Is there a safe way to use `File /r` which will not grab unintended things which might get added to parent-dir in the future?

Answer (score 1):

For that problem of `File /r` that could get unexpected files, I have made the following macro:

```
; SlurpSubDir : include a file pattern from a directory
!macro SlurpSubDir args parentSrcDir subDir pattern parentDstDir
    SetOutPath "${parentDstDir}\${subDir}"
    File ${args} "${parentSrcDir}\${subDir}\${pattern}"
    SetOutPath "${parentDstDir}"
!macroend
!define SlurpSubDir "!insertmacro SlurpSubDir"
```

That I call like this to get the whole `perl` subdirectory from `${InstSrcFiles}` that is the directory where the setup master files are located, with exclusion of possible `.svn` directories, and the files will be installe into `$INSTDIR`:

```
${SlurpSubDir} "/r /x .svn" "${InstSrcFiles}" "perl" "*.*" "$INSTDIR"
```